# Repeat a function call N times

Tags: julia

What's the easiest way in Julia to call a function `n` times, with the same arguments, and return the result in an array? For example, I'd like to get an array of random strings, each of a certain length. The best I've been able to come up with is

```
julia> map(_ -> randstring(4), 1:6)
6-element Array{String,1}:
 "xBWv"
 "CxJm"
 "KsHk"
 "UUIP"
 "64o4"
 "QNgm"
```

Another alternative is to use broadcasting, like in either of the following:

```
# Broadcast over an array of 4's
randstring.(fill(4, 6))

# Broadcast over an iterator that repeats the number 4 six times
using Base.Iterators
randstring.(repeated(4, 6))
```

However, my preference is for a syntax like `replicate(randstring(4), 6)`. For comparison, in R I would do the following:

```r
> # Sample from lower-case letters only:
> random_string <- function(n) paste(sample(letters, n, replace = TRUE), collapse = '')
> replicate(6, random_string(4))
[1] "adru" "neyf" "snuo" "xvnq" "yqfv" "gept"
```

Comment: Consider updating the title to "... in Julia".

Comment: @logankilpatrick The `julia` tag is sufficient to denote the programming language, and you'll find that the tag is also picked up by google and stack overflow searches.

Answer (score 12):

I would go with

```
using Random
six_randstrings = [randstring(4) for _ in 1:6]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're unhappy with using `map` or array comprehensions directly then you could create a macro for this:

```
macro replicate(ex, n)
    return :(map(_ -> $(esc(ex)), 1:$(esc(n))))
end

@replicate(rand(), 4)
```

Comment: I think you need to wrap `ex` and `n` in `esc` in order to be able to use `@replicate` inside another function, like `:(map(_ -> $(esc(ex)), 1:$(esc(n))))`. Try it out on `m, n = 3, 5; foo(m, n) = (m = 2m; n = 2n; @replicate(m, n)); foo(6, 10)`.

Answer (score 1):

While there are ways to do this without introducing package dependencies, [Lazy.jl](https://github.com/MikeInnes/Lazy.jl) does provide a lot of these nice, functional tools.

In particular, you said

> my preference is for a syntax like replicate(randstring(4), 6)

First, note that this is no exactly "calling a function `n` times, because `randstring(4)` is not a function, it is evaluated.

So instead you want to call the anonymous function `n` times, to align with the equation title, in which case your preferred syntax is `replicate(()->randstring(4),6)`

Good news! `Lazy.jl` provides almost this exact syntax with the function `repeatedly`. The only distinction is that it takes `n` as its first argument:
`repeatedly(6,()->randstring(4))`

The other distinction to notice is that this returns, for other reasons, a `LazyList` type, not an `Array`.

Now, it's likely the case that you won't notice the difference, e.g. you can index and broadcast into the `List` like you might an `Array`.

However, if you don't intend on exploiting any of the nice `Lazy` properties and you really do need it to be an `Array` then you can just directly unpack the `List` into `Array`.

Here is a full example:

```
using Random
using Lazy

stringlist = repeatedly(6,()->randstring(4))

stringarray = [stringlist...]
```

Comment: Julia (and every other programming language I know) evaluates the arguments first before making the call. So @Jesse is right, by the time `replicate` is called `randstring(4)` is just a string. Fortunately the anonymous function is a simple fix.

Comment: @tholy R is lazy and won't evaluate arguments until they are used inside the function.

Comment: @tholy Haskell is another language that evaluates function arguments lazily.